# MYSQL: is multiple column name change atomic

Tags: mysql

I have to swap two names of columns in my tables:

```
alter table my_table 
change COLUMN COL1 COL2 VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL,
change column COL3 COL4 VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL;
```

is this command atomic in MYSQL?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to that by chance? :/